# jQuery appending wrong html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this code for my form in jQuery:

```
$('form.ajax_form').on('submit', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_errors_space = $(this).find('.ajax_form_errors:first');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'script',
      url: $(this).attr('action'), 
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      // show success response from server.
      success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(jqXHR);
      },
      // show error response from the server.
      error: function(data, status, error_message) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error_message);
        var errors_html = $("<div class='alert alert-danger'><div>");
        // $(errors_html).append('Status code: ' + data.status + '. Message: ' + error_message);
        if (data.status == 422){
          var error_messages = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
          var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
          for (i in error_messages){
            console.log(error_messages[i]);
            var li = $('<li>' + error_messages[i] +'<li>');
            $(ul).append(li);
          }
          $(errors_html).append(ul);
        }
        console.log('some value');
        console.log($(errors_html));
        form_errors_space.html($(errors_html));
        form_errors_space.show();
      }
    });
  });
```

This generates following HTML:

```
<div class='alert alert-danger'>
  <div></div>
  <ul>
    <li>Content can't be blank</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Interstitial width can't be blank</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Interstitial height can't be blank</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Start date can't be blank</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>End date can't be blank</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Priority can't be blank</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Tag can't be blank</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Is for employees with rewards can't be blank</li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I expect the output to be:

```
<div class='alert alert-danger'>
  <ul>
    <li>Content can't be blank</li>
    <li>Interstitial width can't be blank</li>
    <li>Interstitial height can't be blank</li>
    <li>Start date can't be blank</li>
    <li>End date can't be blank</li>
    <li>Priority can't be blank</li>
    <li>Tag can't be blank</li>
    <li>Is for employees with rewards can't be blank</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Value of `data.responseText` is:

```
"["Content can't be blank","Interstitial width can't be blank","Interstitial height can't be blank","Start date can't be blank","End date can't be blank","Priority can't be blank","Tag can't be blank","Is for employees with rewards can't be blank"]"
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error in

```
var li = $('<li>' + error_messages[i] +'<li>');
```

It should be

```
var li = $('<li>' + error_messages[i] +'</li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `li` you create does not have a closing tag, so you have two `<li>` elements created. The browser is then adding the closing tag for you to try and maintain page validity.

Change this:

```
var li = $('<li>' + error_messages[i] + '<li>');
```

To this:

```
var li = $('<li>' + error_messages[i] + '</li>'); // < note the '/'
```

Or a better method to avoid problems like this:

```
var li = $('<li />', { text: error_messages[i] });
```

Comment: Brain fart. I figured it now. Thank you.